# How to Select all Entrys from one Table, and SUM a subset of another table

Tags: sql-server

I have a larger Database with Times that employees entered. They enter an activity, when it was and how long they spent on it, as well as a customer.

I'm now trying to return a table with all employees, that Sums their times, but only if it's timed for a subset of Customers. I can get either a table with The Correct times, but employees that didn't enter any time are omitted, or I get all employees but with the sum time from all customers.

The tables I have are:

- EMPLOYEE for the employees
- ACTIVITY for all activities
- CUSTOMER for the customers

To have some "example Data":

```
| EMPLOYEE             |    | ACTIVITY                             |
+------------+---------+    +------------+------------+------------+
| I_EMPLOYEE | S_NAME1 |    | I_EMPLOYEE | I_CUSTOMER | N_DURETIME |
+------------+---------+    +------------+------------+------------+
|          1 | A       |    |          1 |          1 |          5 |
|          2 | B       |    |          2 |          3 |         10 |
|          3 | C       |    |          1 |          3 |         15 |
+------------+---------+    |          3 |          2 |         10 |
                            |          1 |          2 |         10 |
                            +------------+------------+------------+
```

What i'd expect to get when i want all times except Customer 2:

```
+----------+----------+
| EMPLOYEE | DURETIME |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |       20 |
|        2 |       10 |
|        3 |        - |
+----------+----------+
```

I get either of those two out:

```
+----------+----------+    +----------+----------+
| EMPLOYEE | DURETIME |    | EMPLOYEE | DURETIME |
+----------+----------+    +----------+----------+
|        1 |       20 |    |        1 |       30 |
|        2 |       10 |    |        2 |       10 |
+----------+----------+    |        3 |       10 |
                           +----------+----------+
```

To get the correct times i use the following:

```
SELECT emp.S_NAME1 AS Mitarbeiter, SUM(act.N_DURETIME)/60 as Zeit
FROM EMPLOYEE AS emp
LEFT JOIN ACTIVITY AS act on act.I_EMPLOYEE = emp.I_EMPLOYEE
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER AS cust on cust.I_CUSTOMER = act.I_CUSTOMER
WHERE cust.CUSTNO NOT '2'
```

to get the full list of employees i used:

```
SELECT emp.S_NAME1 AS Mitarbeiter, SUM(act.N_DURETIME)/60 as Zeit
FROM EMPLOYEE AS emp
LEFT JOIN ACTIVITY AS act on act.I_EMPLOYEE = emp.I_EMPLOYEE
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER AS cust on cust.I_CUSTOMER = act.I_CUSTOMER AND cust.CUSTNO NOT '2'
```

So, depending on whether I put my "Customer Filter" in the `JOIN` or the `WHERE` statement, I get half of the correct table. How can I combine those to get the correct output?

Answer (score 1):

```
Create Table #emp
(
i_emp Int,
s_name1 Char(1)
)
Insert Into #emp Values
(1,'A'),
(2,'B'),
(3,'C')

Create Table #Activity
(
i_emp Int,
i_cust Int,
n_duretime Int
)
Insert Into #Activity Values
(1,1,5),
(2,3,10),
(1,3,15),
(3,2,10),
(1,2,10)
```

Query

```
Select 
   e.i_emp, 
   Sum(Case When a.i_cust = 2 Then Null Else a.n_duretime End) As durationTot
From 
   #emp e Left Join
   #Activity a On e.i_emp = a.i_emp
Group By 
   e.i_emp
```

Result:

```
i_emp   durationTot
1       20
2       10
3       NULL
```

Comment: Yes, works perfectly! Thank you very much. I didn't even think about putting a CASE in the Field Select Area.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query

```
create table Employee(I_EMPLOYEE int, S_NAME1 char(1))
insert into Employee Values (1, 'A'),(2, 'B'),(3, 'C')

create table ACTIVITY (I_EMPLOYEE int, I_CUSTOMER int, N_DURETIME int)
insert into  ACTIVITY Values(1, 1, 5 ),( 2, 3, 10), (1, 3, 15), ( 3, 2, 10), ( 1 , 2 , 10 )

select EMPLOYEE, sum(isnull(DURETIME, 0)) as DURETIME from(
select EMPLOYEE.S_NAME1 as EMPLOYEE, case I_Customer when 2 then 0 else N_DURETIME end as DURETIME from activity
inner join Employee on activity.I_EMPLOYEE = Employee.I_EMPLOYEE
)a group by EMPLOYEE
```

Below is the output

```
I_EMPLOYEE  EMPLOYEE    DURETIME
--------------------------------
1            A          20
2            B          10
3            C           0
```